# Is this character still alive after the events of "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

During *Avengers: Infinity War* Thanos killed Vision to take the [Mind Stone](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Mind_Stone) from his head.

During *Avengers: Endgame* Tony Stark (Iron Man) tells Professor Hulk to bring everyone back as they were 5 years ago, which he does by performing *"the snap"*.

Does this mean that this character was brought back? If so, where was he during the final battle?

Comment: Maybe this will be addressed in the show: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9140560/

Comment: should we update this answer since WandaVision has finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something else to add to the other answers :

Vision can't exist without the mind stone. So to bring him back, you'll need to bring him back with the mind stone on his head, which can't be done if the mind stone is on the gauntlet (as far as we know, even having the 6 stones can't make you create a new stone). So even if resurecting someone was possible, Vision is one of the only creatures in the universe that actually could never be brought back by the stones.

Comment: While not actually confirmed, Infinity War strongly implies that this is not true. Bruce states that Vision is made up of a lot of different components and that there would still be a lot of "Vision" left if they removed the stone. Later, when they task Shuri with safely extracting the stone, she claims that she can do it, albeit not without great risk. But there is more evidence to support that he can exist without the Mind stone than there is to say that he definitely can't.

Answer (score 10):

Nope. Hulk's snap is an... "Unsnap", so to say. The people he brings back are the snapped ones, and Vision was murdered, not snapped.

Note that technically speaking, the Mind Stone that Vision was based on still exists, only in "atoms" in the universe, after Thanos destroyed the Infinity Stones at the beginning of the movie.

From a related interview for the *Hollywood Reporter*:

> **Could the Avengers have brought back Tony Stark back to life using the Infinity Gauntlet?**
>
> *Endgame* saw half of all life in the universe return, thanks to The Hulk (Mark Ruffalo) using the Infinity Gauntlet. Couldn't he have done the same after Tony's death to bring him back?
>
> *Verdict: Nope.*
>
> **"The Gauntlet, as of yet, has not brought back anybody to life that wasn't removed by the Gauntlet.** Tony was physically killed," said Marcus.
>
> <sub>[*'Avengers: Endgame' Writers Take on Biggest Fan Theories*, Aaron Couch for the *Hollywood Reporter*, May 10th, 2019](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/amp/heat-vision/avengers-endgame-writers-confirm-captain-america-fan-theory-1209241)</sub>

Sure, this is about Tony, but it applies to Vision as well - he was physically murdered and while the Time Stone was used to bring him back shortly, the Gauntlet wasn't complete - that's the whole point of it, to get his Stone.

Comment: A sophisticated user of the Infinity Gauntlet could do literally _anything_ by definition, but there's noone around who has that skill. Maybe Odin could have done it. Pure conjecture on my part.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Jenayah's answer, there is also a conversation between Wanda and Hawkeye in the movie which confirms Vision's death:

> “I wish there was a way I could let her [Natasha Romanoff] know that we won,” Hawkeye tells Wanda Maximoff, The Scarlet Witch, at Stark’s memorial. “That we did it.”
>
> “She knows,” says Wanda, who is still grieving the death of The Vision. “They both do.”

Comment: Ironically, letting the dead spirit of someone know something is exactly what the Soul stone is good at. So they could have. see: Thanos talking to young Gamora after the snap.